# How to upgrade ruby 1.9 cartridge in exsting OpenShift Online application?

Tags: ruby, openshift

I have an existing OpenShift Online app that I created with a Ruby 1.9 cartridge.

Now that the Ruby 2.0 cartridge is available I'd like to "upgrade" my app to use that, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I tried doing an 'rhc cartridge-add ruby-2.0 -a ' but it says the cartridge isn't available.

I created a sample rails 4/ruby 2.0 app in my OpenShift Online account so I know the cartridge exists, but for some reason my ruby 1.9 app doesn't know about it.

I'm hoping I don't have to create a whole new app and then migrate my code over, re-populate the database, modify the Gemfile, etc.

Has anyone tried to do this and had success? This will be a periodic task for me, upgrading ruby and rails as they become available. I've upgraded rails already and that mostly involved gem and Gemfile changes, but the ruby cartridge upgrade seems different.

I'm thinking this has to have been worked out. Otherwise, established production apps could never have their language cartridges upgraded...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not remove or upgrade a web cartridge (the main cartridge for your application).  You will have to create a new application with the upgraded cartridge that you want to use and migration your application over manually.  You might be able to use the rhc snapshot save & rhc snapshot restore commands, but I'm not sure if that works between different versions of the same cartridge.

Comment: Okay, I'll move forward with that and check out the rhc snapshot commands. Thanks for the info!